# Matriz espiral en C++

Tags: c++, matrices

Estoy teniendo un problema con mi matriz espiral. Funciona a la perfección, pero necesito que la matriz gire en sentido inverso.

```
25 24 23 22 21  
10 09 08 07 20  
11 02 01 06 19  
12 03 04 05 18  
13 14 15 16 17
```

(Agregue los ceros para una mejor organización en la pregunta)

Lo que necesito es que mi matriz este con las filas invertidas, y que quede algo tal que:

```
21 22 23 24 25  
20 07 08 09 10  
19 06 01 02 11   
18 05 04 03 12  
17 16 15 14 13
```

Mi Codigo es:

```
int Matrix[MatrixN][MatrixN],I=0,LC=MatrixN,LF=MatrixN,j,i,x=MatrixN*MatrixN,T=0;

  while (x!=T){

    for(j=I;j <LC ;j++){Matrix[i][j] = x--;}

    for(i=I+1;i< LF ;i++){Matrix[i][j-1]= x--;}

    for(j= LC-1 ;j>I && i>I+1; j--){Matrix[i-1][j-1]= x--;} 

    for(i=LF-1;i>I+1;i--){Matrix[i-1][j]= x--;}

    I++;
    LC--;
    LF--;
}
```

La matriz SIEMPRE sera cuadrada, en el ejemplo que di, es de 5.

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con simétrica?

Comment: Que es de NxN, en el ejemplo que di, es de 5x5

Comment: Entonces es matriz cuadrada, la simetría es una propiedad diferente.

Comment: Lo curioso de tu código es que si el orden es par, por decir 6, la espiral se invierte automáticamente, ¿eras consciente de esto?

Comment: Es cierto, gracias por remarcarme el error, llevo bastante tiempo frente a la pc y se me pasó . Ahora lo edito.

Comment: Vaya, no me había percatado de ese detalle, siempre lo probé con números impares no se porque

Comment: Me equivoqué, en realidad no se invierte, solo empieza a girar desde otro punto, el sentido antihorario se mantiene, y lo que tu quieres es que gire en sentido horario, si no me equivoco.

Comment: Claro, que vaya como en el ejemplo que coloque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución es ubicar los elementos haciendo como un espejo, fijate:

```
  25 24 23 22 21          21 22 23 24 25
  10 09 08 07 20          20 07 08 09 10
  11 02 01 06 19          19 06 01 02 11
  12 03 04 05 18          18 05 04 03 12
  13 14 15 16 17          17 16 15 14 13
// ^ ^  ^  ^  ^            ^  ^  ^  ^  ^
// 1 2  3  4  5            5  4  3  2  1
```

Con esto se logra el efecto deseado, entonces, en vez de ubicar un elemento en la posición `(i,j)`, lo ubicarías en `(i,n-j-1)`, siendo `n` el orden de la matriz, entonces el código quedaría así:

```
while (x != T) {

    for (j = I; j < LC; j++) { Matrix[i][MatrixN-j-1] = x--; }

    for (i = I + 1; i < LF; i++) { Matrix[i][MatrixN-j] = x--; }

    for (j = LC - 1; j > I && i > I + 1; j--) { Matrix[i - 1][MatrixN - j] = x--; }

    for (i = LF - 1; i > I + 1; i--) { Matrix[i - 1][MatrixN - j - 1] = x--; }

    I++;
    LC--;
    LF--;
}
```

**Nota:** EL código funciona pero al parecer no inicializas `i` ni `j` en cero, que es indispensable para que el código funcione, sus valores son modificados en cada bloque `for` y se usan en el siguiente, procura hacer `int i=0` e `int j=0` para no tener problemas.

Comment: Fantástico! Muchísimas gracias por la explicación! funciona excelente!